# Problems with character-encoding when webscraping with scrapy

Tags: python, character-encoding, web-scraping, scrapy

I have problem with the encoding of the text, I am scraping from a website. Specifically the Danish letters æ, ø, and å are coming out wrong. I feel confident that the encoding of the webpage is UTF-8, since the browser is showing it correctly with this encoding.

I have tried using BeautifulSoup as many of the other posts have suggested, but it wasn't for the better. However, I probably did it wrong.

I am using python 2.7 on a windows 7 32 bit OS.

The code I have is this:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Sale(Item):
    Adresse = Field()
    Pris = Field()
    Salgsdato = Field()
    SalgsType = Field()
    KvmPris = Field()
    Rum = Field()
    Postnummer = Field()
    Boligtype = Field()
    Kvm = Field()
    Bygget = Field()

class HouseSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'House'
    allowed_domains = ["http://boliga.dk/"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?so=1&type=Villa&type=Ejerlejlighed&type=R%%C3%%A6kkehus&kom=&amt=&fraPostnr=&tilPostnr=&iPostnr=&gade=&min=&max=&byggetMin=&byggetMax=&minRooms=&maxRooms=&minSize=&maxSize=&minsaledate=1992&maxsaledate=today&kode=&p=%d' %n for n in xrange(1, 3, 1)]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select("id('searchresult')/tr")
        items = []      
        for site in sites:
            item = Sale()
            item['Adresse'] = site.select("td[1]/a[1]/text()").extract()
            item['Pris'] = site.select("td[2]/text()").extract()
            item['Salgsdato'] = site.select("td[3]/text()").extract()
            item['SalgsType'] = site.select("td[4]/text()").extract()
            item['KvmPris'] = site.select("td[5]/text()").extract()
            item['Rum'] = site.select("td[6]/text()").extract()
            item['Postnummer'] = site.select("td[7]/text()").extract()
            item['Boligtype'] = site.select("td[8]/text()").extract()
            item['Kvm'] = site.select("td[9]/text()").extract()
            item['Bygget'] = site.select("td[10]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

It is the items 'Adresse' and 'Salgstype' that contain æ, ø, and å. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Comment: Don't trust in explorer, check what's the `Character-Encoding` header in the http response. Also, what do you mean about the letter coming out wrong? How are they coming?

Comment: @PauloBu: How do I check the `character-encoding` of the http response? The capital Æ comes out as \xc6 and the small letter æ as \xe6 when I crawl my spider from cmd.exe.

Comment: To check the http response header you either need, chrome, firefox firebug, on the other side, you can trust cmd.exe, first of all, do this from cmd: `chcp 65001` and later run your script and see if the letters are fine now. chcp 65001 will put cmd.exe with utf-8 code page

Comment: can you put the code where you print the results to the cmd?

Comment: @PauloBu: It still looks the same after doing `chcp 65001`. I have Firebug, though, just can't seem to find out where I get the encoding.

Comment: With firebug, under `Net` tab you may see the requests/responses sent by your browser. Check them, also, read my answer. It suggest you to encode the output string to utf-8.

Comment: You are **actually** getting those characters, but encoded in Unicode, you need to encode them in utf-8 and change the code page of the console to see the find in console.

Comment: You'd also need to add request header, see this http://www.datascraping.co/doc/questions/21/encoding-problem-in-website-scraping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok doing some research I finally checked those characters are [indeed those letter but in unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e6/index.htm). Since your `cmd.exe` doesn't *understand* unicode, it dumps the bytes of the characters.

You'll have to encode them first in utf-8 and change the code page of the `cmd.exe` to utf-8

Do this:

To every string you're going to output to the console, call it's method `encode('utf-8')` like this:

```
print whatever_string.encode('utf-8')
```

That's in your code, and in your console, before invoking your script do this:

```
> chcp 65001
> python your_script.py
```

**Tested** this in my python interpreter:

```
u'\xc6blevangen'.encode('utf-8')
>>>'\xc3\x86blevangen'
```

Which is the [exact AE character encoded in utf-8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, good to know that it's the letters in unicode. However, I still have two problems. First of all, `item['Adresse'] = site.select("td[1]/a[1]/text()").extract()` returns `[u'\xc6blevangen']`. Which I guess somehow needs to be changed into a string before using encode. Furthermore, what matters to me is not the output `cmd.exe` but storing the data in a .csv file, will the .encode('utf-8') method work for that as well?

Comment: This is a list with a unicode string: `[u'\xc6blevangen']`. Extract the unicode string and you'll have .encode method: `item['Adresse'][0]`. The console was just an example, if you write it to a `.txt` you'll do ok. Only that the file content will be encoded in utf-8 :)

Comment: Check the proof of concept I made in my answer :)

Comment: When I try to do `u'\xc6blevangen'.encode('utf-8')` in in my python interpreter, it says `LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001`.

Comment: If you run python's interpreter in the cmd.exe with that code page, the interpreter will complaint. Just write the code, encode it strings with utf-8 and write it to a .txt file, characters will appear ok.